# RTK Query: Linking cache for batch queries

Tags: react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a RTK Query endpoint called getUsers which fetches user data in a batch for multiple user ids, provided as an array.

Now I am concerned about caching behaviour. Is there a way I can make RTK Query fetch user data for the missing users only?

for ex

```js
const { data } = useGetUsersQuery([1, 2, 3])
```

should fetch users 1, 2 and 3

now, afterwards

```js
const { data } = useGetUsersQuery([2, 3, 4, 5])
```

should treat this api as fetch users 4 and 5, merge with existing data for 2 and 3. And return the entire data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. RTK Query is not a normalized cache - it is a document cache - which means that every api response is handled completely unrelated to every other api response.

That is mentioned e.g. here in the docs: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/comparison#no-normalized-or-deduplicated-cache

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna use it anyway you should write something like this in your ApiSlice:

```
        query: (params) => ({
          url: '/api/v1/user_comments',
          method: APIMethods.GET,
          params,
        }),
        providesTags,
        serializeQueryArgs: ({ queryArgs }) => {
          const { commentable_id: CommentedObjId } = queryArgs;

          return { CommentedObjId };
        },
        merge: (currentCache, responseData) => {
          const mergedArray = [
            ...currentCache.items,
            ...responseData.items,
          ].sort(
            (a, b) =>
              new Date(b?.created_at).getTime() -
              new Date(a?.created_at).getTime()
          );
          const filteredData = mergedArray.filter(
            (comment, index, array) =>
              index === array.findIndex((c) => c?.id === comment?.id)
          );

          return {
            pagination: responseData.pagination,
            items: filteredData,
          };
        },
        forceRefetch({ currentArg, previousArg }) {
          return currentArg?.page !== previousArg?.page;
        },
        transformResponse: (response) => {
          return response?.data;
        },
      }),
```

`serializeQueryArgs` prop will give you the key to keep only 1 entry for your query

Inside the `forceRefetch` function you should check if there is something new in the `currentArg` –[1,2,3,4,5]– concerning the `previousArg` –[1,2,3]–

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! I am no longer working on this project, but I hope future programmers looking to optimize the cache even more can find this useful!